# How to add an extra label on a scatter plot point in Highcharts Javascript library?

Tags: php, javascript, attributes, label, highcharts

I am using the Highcharts JavaScript library to visualize some float values, which i feed into the js code via php. As you can see in the following picture, on each point's mouseover are now displayed  the two values that correspond to the axes values and the text "text: undefined". [image: Current Visualisation]

**My question is**: Is there a way to display a different text for each point of the scatter plot? I have a text that corresponds to each point, but I haven't found a way to display it.

My JavaScript/php code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'},
        title: {
            text: 'Average 24hrs Sentiment for <?php echo $channel?> by Gender '
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: '
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Hours ([0-24h].[0-60mins])'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Sentiment (N. Bayes) %'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                    this.x +' hrs, '+ this.y +' sentiment, text: ';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 24,
            y: 1,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Female',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: [
            <?php 

            for($j=0;$j<$i1;$j++)
            {
                if($females[$j]['Hour'][0] == "0")
                {
                    echo '['.$females[$j]['Hour'][1].'.'.$females[$j]['Min'].','.$females[$j]['Sent'].'"]';
                }
                else
                    echo '['.$females[$j]['Hour'].'.'.$females[$j]['Min'].','.$females[$j]['Sent'].'"]';

                if(($j+1)!=$i1)
                {
                    echo ",";
                }
            }
        ?>
        ]}, 
            {
            name: 'Male',
            color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
            data: [
            <?php 

            for($j=0;$j<$i2;$j++)
            {
                if($males[$j]['Hour'][0] == "0")
                {
                    echo '['.$males[$j]['Hour'][1].'.'.$males[$j]['Min'].','.$males[$j]['Sent'].',"'.$males[$j]['Text'].'"]';
                }
                else
                    echo '['.$males[$j]['Hour'].'.'.$males[$j]['Min'].','.$males[$j]['Sent'].',"'.$males[$j]['Text'].'"]';

                if(($j+1)!=$i2)
                {
                    echo ",";
                }
            }
            ?>
            ]}]
    });
});
```

});

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is unique to each point, you can pass more than the x and y as values.  In the following [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tc6T/3/) I pass three other values: locked, unlocked, and potential.  Then to access them in the tooltip formatter, do so by using the `this.point.locked`

Comment: Your example was really helpful, I managed to do it to my visualisation. Thank you.

Comment: Changed the sample with simplified:
tooltip: {pointFormat: 'locked:{point.locked}<br />unlocked:{point.unlocked}<br />potential:{point.potential}' }

Answer (score 1):

```
 this.x +' hrs, '+ this.y +' sentiment, text: ';
```

Try to set the text in this code line,
just in order to check whether my suggestion will solve your problem,
try :

```
 this.x +' hrs, '+ this.y +' sentiment, text: '+this.x;
```

And then check whether (this.x) value appears insted of "undefined" .